# Stripe Payment-Update the amount in Java

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created charge. Before capture I need to update the amount. I am getting error saying "Received unknown parameter: amount"
I used the following code.

To Create:

```
       Stripe.apiKey = API_KEY;

       Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       chargeParams.put("amount", (int) (amount * 100));
       chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
       chargeParams.put("capture", !isAuthen)
       Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

To Update:

```
        Charge ch = Charge.retrieve(chargeId,requestOptions);           
        Map<String, Object> updateParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        updateParams.put("amount", (int) (amount * 100));
        ch = ch.update(updateParams);
```

Let me know how I can update the amount.
Thanks!!

Comment: You can not update `amount` for Charge.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do the authorize-capture flow.  This is failing because you can't *update* the amount of a charge; however, you can *capture* an amount less than what you've authorized.  You just need to change your API Calls.

You want to call [Capture Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#capture_charge) with an `amount`-argument, rather than [Update Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_charge).

```
Charge ch = Charge.retrieve(chargeId, requestOptions);           
Map<String, Object> captureParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
captureParams.put("amount", (int) (amount * 100));
ch = ch.capture(captureParams);
```